# 14.04: How to ssh/scp as root with NO password prompting?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, password

We upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04.
We have a dozens of processes that perform automation tasks for us and we use root with ssh/scp. After the upgrade root couldn't ssh/scp into the servers at all. We fixed that issue however no matter what we set the servers always prompts root for a password.

How do you configure ssh/scp so that root is **NOT** prompted for a password when executing ssh/scp?

Comment: IO easiest way is to use  key without a password. Hard to know how to help you from what little you posted.

Comment: We have SSH working. I can login as root (or sudo -i) and ssh/scp to the remote server. However the remote server always prompts root for a password. We created new id_rsa keys and copied them into place (yes, permissions, etc, etc - we have been doing this for a long time). However no matter what we read or do every 14.04 server prompts root for a password before permitting ssh/scp to continue. The 12.04 versions do not prompt for a password.